# Log API calls from an iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there anyway to see api calls that an iPad app makes. Basically like in firebug you can see all API calls made by a site. I'm trying to do the same with iPad apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could. I personally use this to see the stacktrace for each API call. Hope this is what you want.

```
+ (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)sel
{
    NSLog(@"Queried about %@", NSStringFromSelector(sel));
    return [super respondsToSelector:sel];
}
```

Put this in the `.m` file where you want the API call stacktrace.